# How to set the JAVA_HOME environment in ADF for an Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I'm writing an Azure Function in Python which connects to an IBM informix database. I'm using `jaydebeapi` as the connection library, and connecting using JDBC.
However, when I run the connection code

```
conn = jaydebeapi.connect(...)
```

The error I get is  `No JVM shared library file (libjvm.so) found. Try setting up the JAVA_HOME environment variable properly.`

My suspicion is that I need to set the JAVA_HOME variable for the function, but I have no idea how to do so for an Azure Function in ADF, nor where the directory should point to. How would I go about this?

Please don't reply with answers about the ADF linked service to Informix, I know about it, I don't want it, I need to do this via an Azure Functions for reasons.

I have not tried anything because I am not sure how to start on this process. Searches online have yielded no results since this is a very unique situation (I think).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install the JVM in your Function connected to ADF, You need to SSH into your function app by Advance tools kudu and then run the commands below:-

```bash
apt-get  update
apt-get install default-jdk
java -version
which java
```

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now Add this path in as `JAVA_HOME` in the Function App settings like below: -

**`JAVA_HOME:/usr/bin/java`**

[image]

Comment: So I can't see this SSH button when I navigate to that UI, is that a permissions thing?

Comment: Upgrade your Function app to higher tier